# will C++ 11 extern template help to reduce executable file size

Tags: c++11

I am using g++ on linux with C++ generic programming. I am not using "extern template" key word now, because I tried and sometimes it ended up with "undefined reference to". I know this is probably my fault, but I wouldn't take this risk. My question is, in addition to reducing compile time, will this key word also help to reduce the executable file size? I am suspecious that the executable file has multiple same objects in different modules in the same executable file...

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not reduce final executable size. The "extern template" prevents implicit instantiation in the translation unit. Without "extern template" implicit instantiation of the
same template may happen in several translation units, but the linker will still remove redundant copies and leave only a single.